# Creating a Simple Calculator, having an issue with the addition

Tags: c++, addition

I'm trying to create a simple calculator and i already encountered an issue when addition is being used. I created a function for addition and whenever i pass in two values i get a different answer. For Example when i add 4,5 i would expect to get 9 but the answer i get is **0029144C** . Im still a beginner, so at first i wasn't sure if using type bool for the adding function would affect my result, but i changed it to type float and still getting the same result (in case anyone asks).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void SimCalcMenu();
void additionSign();
bool makeSum(float num1, float num2);

int main() {

    float firstNum, SecondNum;
    char operationLetter;



    SimCalcMenu();
    cout << " Please Select an Operation You Would Like to Perform ";
    cin >> operationLetter;

    if (operationLetter == 'a' || operationLetter == 'A')
    {
        additionSign();
        cout << " Enter the First Number : ";
        cin >> firstNum;

        cout << " Enter the Second Number: ";
        cin >> SecondNum;

        makeSum(firstNum, SecondNum);


        cout << " The Sum of " << firstNum << " and " << SecondNum << " is :" << makeSum << endl;




    }

    else
    {
        cout << " Error ";
    }



    return 0;
}

void SimCalcMenu() {

    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "        WELCOME TO SIM CALCULATOR          " << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " Please Select an Operation :  " << endl;
    cout << " A.) Addition " << endl;
    cout << " B.) Subtraction " << endl;
    cout << " C.) Multiplication " << endl;
    cout << " D.) Division       " << endl;
    cout << " E.) Roots ( Only Positive Number)" << endl;
    cout << " F.) Power ( Only Positive Number " << endl;
    cout << " G.) Percentage                   " << endl;
    cout << " H.) Display functions execution  " << endl;
    cout << " I.) Quit                         " << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

}

void additionSign() {

    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "        ADDITION          " << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;




}




bool makeSum(float num1, float num2) {

    float totSum;

    totSum = num1 + num2;

    return totSum;

}
```

Comment: why does `makeSum` return a `bool` ? if you type `makeSum` alone it refers to the function pointer. You might want to review the chapter about functions in your book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`makeSum()` should return float, because you are returning the sum of two floats.

You are not getting the right result because you are printing `makeSum`, which is the address of the function.  You want to print the value of `makeSum(firstNum, SecondNum)`.

Answer (score 4):

this line

```
  cout << " The Sum of " << firstNum << " and " << SecondNum << " is :" << makeSum << endl;
```

IS 'printing' 'makesum', makesum is a function so its printing the address of makesum

you need

```
  cout << " The Sum of " << firstNum << " and " << SecondNum << " is :" << makeSum(firstNum, SecondNum) << endl;
```

now at least it will print the result of `makesum`. As other have pointerd out that function is wrong (it returns a bool).

should be

```
float makeSum(float num1, float num2) {
    float totSum;
    totSum = num1 + num2;
    return totSum;
}
```